# Codes doesn't work in formulated cell (ex. vlookup)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Anyone who can help me with this?
Why my codes wont work in formulated cell?
I want to run my codes in formulated cell like vlookup
Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // 0 == first sheet.
  var ee = ss.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  if (ee == "A1") { // Check if edited cell is the one we're watching.
    if (e.value == "DONE"){ // If the value == "DONE", do stuff.
      var toggle = sh.getRange("A1:M1");

      for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
      if( i%2 == 0  )
        toggle.setBackground("GOLD");
      else
        toggle.setBackground("WHITE");

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Error messages, crash, freeze, unexpected behavior, something else?

Comment: There’s no event parameter.

Comment: My codes work when I do something directly in cell A1 it will change the background (Like blinker: Gold, White). But if I put formula in cell A1 (Like vlookup, =, . . . etc. ) that will get something on other cell and paste it on A1 my codes wont work.

Answer (score 0):

On edit and on change triggers only are fired by changes directly made by the user, not when the result of a formula changes or a change is made by code.

Use conditional formatting instead.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem Sir? cause I really need to run a blinker in a formulated cell.